# Sticky element's height is undesirably being added to parent element's height and/or increasing scrolling before reaching bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I have a sticky google maps instance (needs to have an explicit height) inside a main tag. There is content on the left side of screen (varies in height depending on db response) that user can scroll thru while map sticks, then once footer is reached map doesn't stick. All this works fine, except that the height of the map (100vh) is being added to the end of the content so there is just blank space to scroll thru at the end. No amount of messing with main's height or overflow, and whatnot seems to get me the desired behavior and have this blank space removed. Even if I place map-wrapper outside of  its height is magically added into the amount of scrolling to get to bottom. The behavior I'm looking for is like AirBnb's search view with list on left side and map on right.

```css
.map-wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 48rem;
  width: calc(100% - 48rem);
}

.map {
  height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
}

.left {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 48rem;
}

main {
  margin-top: 4rem;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
}
```

```html
<main>
<div>
    <div class="left">
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="map-wrapper">
        <div class="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: FYI you are missing a closing div tag for `.map`. Not sure if that's also missing in your actual code or was just a transcription error. Anyway we need to see some actual (or filler) content that represents what you're seeing to better assist you.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are having the default margin of body tag, so 100vh will result in some scroll. To prevent this, you can use either body{margin:0} or better, the reset code i usually use *{margin:0;padding:0} to remove any/all default space (either margin or padding) of any tag then you can manually change them to your prefer style if needed.

Comment: Thanks y'all. But unfortunately not. This is a react project but the issue is purely html/css so I chopped the code up a bit. The content is a ul with li's that contain bootstrap cards. Basically no matter what I do, I have to scroll across blank space that is equivalent to the height of the map (however big the viewport is) before I get to the footer, at which point the map becomes "unstuck" as it should.

Comment: Ok, too busy to invest more now, but the target web you mention use absolute instead of static, so you sure you want to use static?

Comment: Are you talking about how airbnb's google map instance shows absolute? ...I don't know how they are able to use absolute but still have the map scroll when the footer is reached, but this seems to be exact use case that sticky was made for so I tried it and it so easily got me 90% of the way there. But if I could figure out how to do it with absolute I'm all for it, I'll research, haven't gone that route yet.